# Variation French site does not show all the Global Navigations in french(target) site for user with read permission

Tags: permissions, variations, managed-navigation

I have a variation publishing site with English and French.  http://portal.... /sites/HR/en-ca/ & http://portal.... /sites/HR/fr-ca/ I am using managed navigation and global navigation is based on managed metadata
[image]

I have a security issue In my target variation site, I can see all the terms when I log in as administrator or with full control permission in target(French), but when I login with just read permission(tempuser) to my French site, the navigation items are not visible (ie I should see 9 items but I don’t see these items) in my global navigation. Any idea?

[image]
[image]